# Duplicate mounting of USB drive on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, mount, partition, usb

I have a problem that I have never encountered before, so I have no idea where to begin TS.
One of my external USB drives, named Tolotupon, has always mounted properly. I had done nothing to the system prior to the issue. 
Now when it mounts I have Tolotupon (unreadable/unwriteable) and Tolotupon1 (readable&writeable).

I have done a system update, but there was no change.

I am running Mint "Tessa" 4.15.0-58-generic 64bit.

I am completely befuddled. What could be causing this?

Comment: This may be complete fishing in the dark, but give 4.15.0-55 a try. I had problems with 4.15.0-58-generic with Ubuntu 16.04 when mounting SD cards. The problem disappeared when using -55.